# Data Extension field has Colon

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I am attempting to use an exclusion script on my emails in Journey Builder.
We are loading a data extension with opportunities that we would want to exclude from the send. Our exclusion looks like this:

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS('This--is--the--name--of--our--data--ext', 'Id', Opportunity:Id))>0`

The 'Id' field is the field on our exclusion data extension we're referencing
and the Opportunity:Id field is the name of the field in the journey that matches

When I try and validate my journey I am getting the following error

> *Exclusion filter validation failed: Exclusion filter is invalid. Error 1 Invalid Function Call The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. Function Call: LOOKUPROWS('This--is--the--name--of--our--data--ext', 'Id', Opportunity:Id) Attribute or Field Name: Opportunity:Id Invalid Content >>> ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS('This--is--the--name--of--our--data--ext', 'Id', Opportunity:Id))*

I believe this error is caused by the ":" in the Opportunity Id field name. I have tried putting [ ] and { } around the field name with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributeValue) around your personalization string:

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS('DENAME', 'Id', AttributeValue("Opportunity:Id"))) > 0`

Comment: I'm a proud member of the #NoNakedPersonalizationStrings fan club.